# Get length of class with certain HTML

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how many elements of the page with the class "test" contain the HTML "test123".

```
$('.test').html('test123').length;
```

Obviously this sets the html of every `.test`-Element  to "test123" which is not what I want...

a workaround could be something like

```
var count = 0;
$('.test').each(function(){
    if($(this).html() == 'test123'){
       count++;
    }
});
```

But there has to be something simpler than that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:contains` in jquery

```
$(".test:contains('test123')").length
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('.test:contains(test123)').length;
```

> [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) : Select all elements that contain the specified text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function to filter the elements with certain condition(like elements having html test123 in your case):

```
var count = $('.test').filter(function(){
       return $(this).html()=="test123";
}).length;
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5LU3C/)**

Answer (score 0):

this is the way to go:

```
var counter=0;
$('.test').each(function(){
    if($(this).html()=='test123'){
        counter++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why? You simply reused the workaround provided in the question.

Comment: this wasn't in the question when I answered! but seems like it doesn't work, which I believe it should!

Comment: I believe the problem is not that it doesn't work but that the solution is considered too elaborate or inefficient by the asker.

Comment: I agree it's not the best solution!